# Downloading Picture Uploaded to Bot From Sharepoint Returns 403 FORBIDDEN

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, botframework

I'm using the Bot Framework v4 SDK. I'm trying to download a picture that I upload to Microsoft Teams via the bot into a temporary directory, then use that picture. I'm motivated to do this because I need to take a picture a user attaches to a chat, then put this picture into a document and return the document back to the user. This works when I run it on the emulator, but I get errors once the bot is in Teams.

I prompt the user for a photo via an AttachmentPrompt:

```
return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
    "imagePrompt",
    new PromptOptions
    {
        Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please attach a picture."),
    });
```

Grab the attachment from the stepContext.Result:

```
List<Attachment> contextAttachmentResult = (List<Attachment>)stepContext.Result;
```

Determine where the file is hosted

```
var remoteFileUrl = contextAttachmentResult[0].ContentUrl;
```

Set a path for the system's temporary directory

```
var tempImagePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), contextAttachmentResult[0].Name);
```

And attempt to download the file using a `WebClient`

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Other");
    webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", userProfile.Token);
    webClient.DownloadFile(remoteFileUrl, tempImagePath);
}
```

I've tried putting the token in I get from the `OAuthPrompt`, but I still get a 403. The 403 occurs right when I try to download it. The reason I think this is a SharePoint issue is because if I print out `remoteFileUrl` I get `https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/my_name/Documents/Microsoft Teams Chat Files/someImage.png`

The beginning of the stack trace is:

`System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) FORBIDDEN. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)`

Edit:
as per Mick's comment, I've attempted to use the `ConnectorClient` in this way (and trying two different ways of downloading it):

```
using (var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(stepContext.Context.Activity.ServiceUrl, MYAPPID, MYAPPPASSWORD)))
{
    var token = await (connectorClient.Credentials as MicrosoftAppCredentials).GetTokenAsync();
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(contextAttachmentResult[0].ContentType));
        var byteArray = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(remoteFileUrl);

    }
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Other");
        webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
        webClient.DownloadFile(remoteFileUrl, siteReviewFile1ImagePath);
    }
}
```

but I get a 401 even though I've set up my connector to use my appId and appPwd `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__30.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at IBIBot.Dialogs.SiteReviewSpace.SiteReviewDialog.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<-ctor>b__2>d.MoveNext() in`

I'm still confused as to how to get this download

Comment: Are you using Bot Framework v3 or v4? You need to use the access token from the Bot Connector, not the access token from the user which you retrieve using the OAuth card.

Comment: I'm using v4. I've had trouble getting the Bot Connector to work at all, I'm guessing it doesn't work with v4. I'll edit my post to include the version I'm using.

Comment: I'm now attempting to get the Bot Connector working. I'm having trouble getting past a 401 Unauthorized. I believe this is because my `connectorClient.Credentials` has null values. I'll post more info. Maybe this is a bug on its own, however it's more likely I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved by not using the Attachment.ContentUrl but instead the Attachment.Content.DownloadUrl. The downloadurl is a preauthorized download so doesn't need any of the bearer or authorization headers.
My code looked something like this:

```
var remoteFileUrl = ((JObject)contextAttachmentResult[0].Content)["downloadUrl"].ToString();
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile(remoteFileUrl, someFileLocationPath);
}
```